# iOS 10.2.1 - Enterprises Apps Fail to Verify [iPhone]

Tags: ios

Whenever I go to `General > Device Management` and try to verify apps from a developer, it fails. I press `"Verify"` then it says `"Verifying"` on top like it's supposed to, with the circle loading bar but then it stops and gives no messages at all.

It was working the night before. Any help?

Comment: clean the build, then fore quit xcode. go so settings on your mac, then to accounts, log off then log in with your Apple ID again. Then open xcode again. This should fix the problem!

Comment: I forgot to add it's on an iPhone... sorry. 

Comment: Great! can you please answer you question and mark it as correct for the question to be useful for others? and If you found my comment helpful please upvote!

Comment: Thing is though, I don't know how to "clean the build" and "force quit Xcode" on iPhone. I never knew these things existed honestly. Sorry. Also I think the answer you provided is for Mac.

Comment: cleaning the build (Command + shift + K) and force quit is (Command + Q). Good luck!

Comment: But I'm on an  iPhone, not on a  MacBook.

Comment: Oh okay I thought the xcode! my bad